# Any php function which would display all alphanumerics?

Tags: php

I have to define a variable as a string of all alphabets(upper & lowercase) & digits.
Currently i am doing it in the following way.

```
 $string = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
```

Is there any other way to define $string which would have same value ?

Comment: There's lots of different ways.  Why do you _want_ to do it a different way?  What are you actually trying to achieve with this string?

Comment: If you want to check other strings for validity, you might want to take a look at regexs. What's the purpose of your `$string`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use php range for this:

```
$string = join(array_merge(range(0, 9), range('A', 'Z'), range('a', 'z')));
```

Comment: Perfectly correct answer, only funny that it has nearly the same amount of chars to produce the same result :)

Comment: Yeah but doing it this way you won't miss any char :)